# swift function () -> (Int) -> String

Tags: swift, function, currying

given the following function:

```
func returnFunc() -> (Int) -> String {
    func innerFunc(i: Int) -> String {
        return " value returned : \(i)"
    }
    return innerFunc
}

returnFunc()    // (Int) -> String -- (correct)
returnFunc()(5) // 'value returned: 5'
```

why do I need to provide () followed by (5) to get this result ?

I need to understand how the 5 value is given to the argument "i" of innerFunc

I'll really appreciate any pointer which explains this feature.

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_function_returning_function

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_curried_functions

Answer (score 1):

Because the return of `returnFunc` is a function which means

```
returnFunc() = innerFunc
```

so this

```
returnFunc()(5)
```

means

```
innerFunc(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

`returnFunc` is a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function, whose type can be also written as `func returnFunc() -> ((Int) -> String)`, since it is actually a function that takes no input arguments and returns another function that takes a single input argument of type `Int` and returns a `String`.

So by calling `returnFunc()`, you simply return a function, namely `innerFunc`, but you need to pass an input argument to `innerFunc` to be able to execute it. This is done by the `(5)` at the end of `returnFunc()(5)`.

It becomes more clear if you write it out in steps:

```
let innerFunc = returnFunc()
let fiveString = innerFunc(5) // "value returned: 5"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `returnFunc()` instantiates a new instance of a function that takes an integer and returns a string.

`returnFunc()(5)` also calls the function and passes `5` as the argument to this returned function, due to the way they are chained together.

It’s a little bit like if a function returned an array, you would access an array element with:

```
func returnArray() -> [Int] {
    return [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
}

returnArray()[2] // This evaluates to 2
```